# Parameter bound to an Angular 2 root component is null

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm trying to bind a parameter to my Angular 2 root component that I can use within the `ngOnInit` method, for example

```
<workspace [testparam]="test"></workspace>
```

In the constructor of the workspace-component.ts file I attempt to get the attribute on the element

```
constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
    this.testparam = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('testparam');
}
```

and in the `ngOnInit` method I try to alert this value

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    alert("Value:" + this.testparam );
}
```

Which is giving me

> Value:null

From what I read this is the way to work around this issue, am I missing something?

Comment: To accomplish such functionality use can use Angular2 Directive. Please refer https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja There is no way to use directives on the root component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead

```
<workspace testparam="test"></workspace>
```

There is no binding syntax support outside the Angular root component template.

Comment: Just got one of those hand against the forehead moments! Thank you!

Comment: Nothing to worry, it's Monday ;-)